# Significado y gramática de "niñas bien"

Tags: modismos, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, sintaxis

Hace poco he visto la publicidad de un jabón de uso vaginal que dice ser "*el de las niñas bien*". La entonación del anuncio es claramente mexicana.

Yo soy chileno y hace mucho tiempo había escuchado la expresión "*gente bien*" para referirse a los ricos, aunque esta frase me parece que ya no se usa.

Entonces me da curiosidad saber a quiénes se refiere la expresión "niñas bien", en qué países se usa y cómo se originó, o si es sólo un juego de palabras que se permitieron los publicistas. No creo que se trate de "niñas buenas", porque ser bueno no es precisamente un atributo atractivo para vender mercancías. Además quiero saber qué tan permitido está usar el adverbio *bien* como si fuera un adjetivo.

Comment: De hecho, sí; *bien* funciona como adjetivo en este caso para denotar a la gente que posee buena situación.

Comment: I just want to add a note, as I had an incorrect answer here, which was worded as a guess, and it was wrong. I guessed it because I had no knowledge of an invariant form of bien. I do think it is wrong to delete incorrect answers, if only because it closes the door on someone learning from the mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Según el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*, la cuarta acepción de "[bien](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=bien)" es la siguiente:

> 4. Como adjetivo invariable significa ‘de buena posición social’: *«Vivían en Miraflores, balneario de la gente bien»* (Ribeyro *Geniecillos* [Perú 1983]); *«El tango fue llevado a Europa por esos “niños bien” y la alta sociedad de allá la* [sic] *adoptó con entusiasmo, creyendo que era una danza de la alta sociedad de acá»* (Feldman *Guión* [Arg. 1996]).

En ella podemos ver que citan ejemplos recientes (a lo más 30 años) tanto de Perú como de Argentina.

Según el [diccionario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5TkGdE0), es un uso coloquial:

> 17. adj. coloq. De posición social y económica elevada. *Casa, gente bien. Familias bien.*

También soy de Chile, y acá las únicas veces que lo he  escuchado en el habla cotidiana, es siempre con un énfasis un tanto irónico.

Comment: Sospecho que originalmente se decía *gente de bien* y el *de* acabó perdiéndose, convirtiendo así *bien* en adjetivo. La letra de la canción *LIgia Elena*, por ejemplo, habla de los *niños de bien*, claramente con este mismo significado.

Comment: @Gorpik No deja de ser interesante. De hecho en mi país se sigue usando, no con la misma frecuencia, pero he escuchado a gente ocupar esa afirmación.

Comment: En Argentina se sigue usando *gente bien*, *chicos bien*, *familia bien*, pero siempre en tono irónico, quizá porque es políticamente incorrecto usarlo en su sentido original (ya que connota que la posición socioeconómica se relaciona con la altura moral). También se dice irónicamente *gente como uno* con un significado parecido.

Answer (score 1):

Buen intento, pero todos ustedes no tienen la respuesta correcta.
"Niñas bien" en México se refiere a chicas de edad entre 16 y 19 años que gustan de llevar una vida jovial y sana, además de tener sus valores familiares bien presentes. Suele ser chicas que son de familia, cursando la secundaria o preparatoria y que se involucran en actividades de jóvenes normales, como ir al cine, salir a bailar o de compras; todo esto sin caer en situaciones que las califique como libertinas o promiscuas.
El comercial hace énfasis en las infecciones vaginales que incluso chicas responsables y de familias de buenas costumbres pueden padecer. Es decir, no porque tengas este tipo de infecciones querrá decir que eres una chica fácil o una ramera. Esto ultimo acá en México es muy importante en la reputación de una chica.

Comment: Buenas, no entiendo porque dices que la respuesta aceptada no es correcta. Cuando dices que son chicas de familia, ¿qué significa exactamente? En España "niñas bien" tiene el mismo sentido que indica Nicolás, niñas cuyas familias son de posición social y económica elevada. Pijas, hablando en plata.