# Origen del uso de "Charo(s)" en las redes sociales

Tags: españa, neologismos, jerga-internet, insultos

Poniéndome al día de los eventos políticos en España he dado con nuevos neologismos.

El primeros sería "cayetanos". Iba a hacer una pregunta al respecto justo ayer, pero en su más reciente podcast (hasta el momento) "El país de las cacerolas", Fernando Díaz Villanueva explica que [el origen del término](https://youtu.be/ErgRURBup6w?t=703) es una canción del grupo español de rock Carolina Durante, [Los Cayetanos](https://youtu.be/ZiUhV12G024), que se mofa de los niños pijos o ["niños bien"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16165/5481) <sup>1</sup>.

El segundo sería el uso de "charo" (o charos) para referirse desde grupos ideológicos (en principio) de derechas de forma burlona o peyorativa a mujeres de grupos ideológicos (en principio) de izquierda. Para contextualizar, imaginaos una discusión sobre feminismo en <strike>ese estercolero de bilis llamado</strike> Twitter entre una usuarios de izquierda radical y un usuario "muy de derechas". Ella le termina tachando a él de "señoro"<sup>2</sup> y él a ella de "charo".

Yo no tengo Twiter, y estos términos solo los he oído y visto escrito alguna vez, por lo que no puedo dar ejemplos concretos, pero estoy bastante seguro que el término "charo" designa, de forma burlona o peyorativa, a usuarias de (o en) redes sociales que expresan ideas sobre feminismo afines a la izquierda más radical.

El origen de "Cayetanos" me queda claro que es por una canción y el de "señoros" es muy obvio. ¿De dónde viene lo de llamar "Charo(s)" en las redes sociales a estas usuarias?

---

1. Lo incluyo por añadir un poco al contexto,  ya puesto para que aprendamos algo nuevo. Iba a ser una pregunta por contestar, y ahora es una pregunta (casi) autocontestada...
2. Otro neologismo, pero el origen de este es muy obvio.

Comment: Pues soy muy asiduo de Twitter y de noticias políticas y nunca he oído _charo_ en este sentido. Me estaré haciendo viejo

Comment: ¡Glups!, yo me llamo Charo de verdad y no tenía ni idea de esto.

Comment: Pues yo coincido con @fedorqui, suelo moverme por Twitter, pero también es que sigo a un grupo reducido de gente cercana y no me meto en discusiones, así que muchos neologismos se me escaparán.

Comment: En la revista *Vanity Fair* aparece el artículo
["De las 'Marujas' a las 'Charo': ¿qué hace que un nombre propio se vuelva meme?"](https://www.revistavanityfair.es/cultura/articulos/ser-una-charo-que-es-nombres/41898) que explica algo sobre el origen de este uso de "Charo".

Comment: @Charo Creo que ahí está la clave. Deberías extractar algo de ese artículo y convertirlo en una respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la revista *Vanity Fair* se encuentra el artículo ["De las 'Marujas' a las 'Charo': ¿qué hace que un nombre propio se vuelva meme?"](https://www.revistavanityfair.es/cultura/articulos/ser-una-charo-que-es-nombres/41898) que explica el fenómeno mencionado en la pregunta:

> Si en los próximos días usted escribe un tweet que alcanza cierta viralidad a favor del pacto PSOE-UP, en apoyo a la víctima de Pozoblanco de la Manada o de Carlota Prado de Gran Hermano, hablando del sastisfyer y/o con una foto de sus gatos, y si además de todo eso es usted una mujer, espérese que alguien le conteste “ok, Charo” o le retuitee con el comentario: “Aquí la típica Charo”. Pero yo me llamo Marisa, dirá usted. Da igual: “Charo” es el nuevo insulto-fetiche de la derecha exaltada española [...].

Según este artículo, la difusión de este uso de "Charo" tiene que ver con la definición que hizo un usuario de *Forocoches*:

> [...] y para definirlo hay que acudir (qué remedio) a **Forocoches**. Allí, un usuario definió “Charo” como “una mujer soltera/divorciada de más de 20 ó 35 años, generalmente sin hijos, se caracteriza por vivir sola, estar siempre amargada, vivir sola, bueno con sus gatos”. Y añade: “ha tenido, tiene y tendrá problemas de depresión, el prozac es un clásico de su vida y su vida se limita a un consolador de su color favorito”. Y como ejemplo, añade un enlace a la noticia de la mujer que se casó con sus gatos.

También se explica cómo este fenómeno ha empezado a extenderse en Twitter:

> En esa línea, alguien creó en octubre un perfil falso de Twitter, @charofeminista, con la bio: “Muy feminista, socialista y progresista #YoConPedro. Licenciada en la Universidad de la Vida”. La cuenta lleva publicados solo dos tweets y dos retweets, entre ellos uno que dice: “El satisfyer me ha hecho disfrutar más del sexo en tres días que mi exmarido en 15 años”. Con dos likes y dos retweets, no se puede decir que sea un éxito viral. Pero aun así, el término ha empezado a extenderse. Hay quien lo ha ilustrado con una foto de la actriz Anabel Alonso y quien le ha dedicado un “starter pack” que incluye, cómo no, el satisfyer, un libro de Elvira Lindo, un disco de Ana Belén y Víctor Manuel, un tinte para canas (marrón y no caoba), una camiseta morada como para ir al 8M, el Prozac, una cajetilla de Marlboro y un mechero del PSOE.

Pero, por lo visto, su uso en foros por parte de usuarios con ideología de derechas se remonta al [año 2011](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D9gO4htWwAAhe7Y?format=png&name=small):

> En foros de la derecha asilvestrada ya se usaba el término desde 2011. En esa fecha, un post describió a las “charos” como “funcionarias de la administración local, comarcal, nacional y de la enseñanza”, fans de Carmen Machi, Lucía Etxebarría y Maruja Torres, seguidoras de *El País* y de *La Sexta*.

Lo que no queda claro es por qué se decidió usar el nombre de Charo de este modo.

Comment: ["Maruja"](https://dle.rae.es/marujo?m=form), que también tiene sus connotaciones despectivas, es "Hipocorístico del nombre propio `María`", que entiendo que es de los más comunes. Entiendo que "Charo" fue elegido casi al azar por cualquiera de esos tipejos. No sé si la intención, consciente o inconsciente, es que esa "Ch" de charo suene como "choni", que también es despectivo, aunque no tiene nada que ver con la imagen que promueve "charo". Viendo de dónde viene y cómo fue acuñado el término, no creo que merezca la pena investigar más.

Comment: @Diego:  De hecho, el artículo de *Vanity Fair* afirma: «En cualquier caso, es mucho más habitual que los nombres marcados (para mal) sean los de mujer debido a un mecanismo de sesgo sexista, clasista o ambas cosas a la vez». Esta es la triste realidad :(

Answer (score 3):

Discrepo de Fernando Díaz Villanueva, creo que está algo desinformado. El origen del término "cayetano" para designar a un "niño bien" es bastante anterior a la aparición de [la canción de Carolina Durante](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiUhV12G024) - que se titula ***Cayetano***, no *Los Cayetanos* - lanzada en **2018**.

¿Cuál considero yo que es el origen del neologismo, no tan neo? Entiendo que la mayoría conocemos a la celebérrima [Casa de Alba](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_de_Alba), familia aristocrática española del más rancio abolengo, cuyos miembros aparecen desde hace centurias en los libros de historia. Si nos acercamos un poco más a la actualidad, varios de sus integrantes han aparecido asiduamente en las páginas de papel cuché. La difunta [Duquesa **Cayetana** Fitz-James Stuart y Silva se casó en **1947**](https://www.revistavanityfair.es/sociedad/articulos/una-boda-cayetana-luis-irujo-sevilla-dior-3000-invitados-chicote-luna-de-miel-seis-meses/39293) y desde entonces hasta su fallecimiento, su presencia ha sido una constante en la prensa rosa y los programas del corazón españoles.

Su hijo menor, **Cayetano** Martínez de Irujo, algo más modestamente en cuanto a volumen de presencia, ha cogido el relevo de su progenitora.

Quizás desconozcáis que temporalmente dicha familia unió sus destinos a otra gran saga, algo menos aristocrática pero de tendencias bastante **conservadoras**, los Rivera Ordoñez, cuando [Francisco Rivera se desposó con Eugenia Martínez de Irujo](https://www.revistavanityfair.es/sociedad/articulos/boda-fran-rivera-eugenia-martinez-de-irujo/41252) en **1998**. ¿Sabéis como se llama el hermano de Francisco? **Cayetano**. El ratio de **Cayetanos** por metro cuadrado en esa boda podría haber entrado en el libro Guinnes de los Records.

Más recientemente aún, **Cayetana** Álvarez de Toledo, casualmente miembro de otra aristocrática familia, los Marqueses de Casa Fuerte, ha decidido dedicarse a la política como uno de los militantes más beligerantes y controvertidos del **conservador** partido político que actualmente ocupa la bancada de la oposición.

¿Vais viendo la pauta?

Nombres como Cayetano o **Borja Mari**, parecen ser mucho más comunes en barrios de clase alta, de Sevilla y Madrid (*) sobre todo, que en barrios obreros. Digo "parecen" porque no dispongo de datos que aportar aquí. Editado: Bueno, alguno sí que he encontrado en la página del [INE](https://www.ine.es/widgets/nombApell/index.shtml)

[image: Cayetanos]

Podemos constatar que hay pocos Cayetanos. Como hay pocos ricos. ¿Casualidad?
Compárese con el número de Franciscos. Además, vemos que no era baladí la distinción entre Andalucía Occidental y Oriental. No vea, canío ;-P
Eso sí, en Madrid hay menos de lo que esperaba (Más oscuro, más personas llamadas Cayetano). No pongo el de "Borja María" pero os informo de que casi todos los 52 están repartidos entre **Madrid** y País Vasco y tienen una edad media de 30.

[image: Franciscos]

Todos los Cayetanos y Cayetanas que he mencionado antes son representantes, epítomes quizás, de una clase social, y unos valores comunes determinados que nos recuerdan poderosamente al [nacional catolicismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacionalcatolicismo) y que podríamos resumir en misa, bandera, unidad nacional, añoranza de la gloria imperial, familia, feria y toros, no al aborto, etc. También comparten una prenda de vestir que los distingue, el [fachaleco](https://elpais.com/elpais/2019/11/15/eps/1573837598_003267.html), que abriga mucho cuando vas de cacería. O eso dicen. ¿Os suena [La escopeta nacional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_escopeta_nacional) de Berlanga de **1978**?

Por todo esto a los manifestantes de los barrios ricos, como el de Salamanca en Madrid, que piden libertad para poder cortarse el pelo o para poder desplazarse a su tercera residencia, localizada junto a un campo de golf o un puerto deportivo, o que gritan consignas patrióticas megáfono en mano mientras su chofer los pasea en descapotable, se les conoce como **cayetanos** y su acción de protesta como **cayeborroka**.

Resumiendo: **Ambos nombres ya se usaban para designar a niños bien mucho antes de que apareciera la canción del grupo madrileño**. Tanto la banda como Twitter solo han dado mayor visibilidad recientemente a un fenómeno previo.

Editaré esta entrada cuando vaya encontrándome con referencias o si alguien amablemente las proporciona en los comentarios.

Finalizo ya para sumarme a lo comentado por Fedorqui y Charlie: siendo asiduo de Twitter no he visto el término "charo" por ningún lado, pero temo que, como el de todo el mundo, mi feed esté bastante sesgado.

(*) Cero personas llamadas Cayetano conozco en Málaga capital. Quizás no me muevo en los círculos adecuados.

Comment: ¿No hay algún que otro Cayetano en la calle Larios? :P

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Manifestantes cayetanos supongo que tenemos por ahí, sí pero no pillo la referencia a calle Larios. No sé si te refieres a otra cosa. Antiguamente puede pero ya no es su habitat natural ;-P Es centro histórico comercial, bastante desangelado estos días, como todos lamentamos.

Comment: Sí bueno en las noticias de estos días se hablaba mucho de esa calle, por ser donde al parecer se están manifestando (https://www.laopiniondemalaga.es/multimedia/fotos/malaga/2020-05-21-185723-millar-personas-manifiesta-contra-gestion-pedro-sanchez-calle-larios.html). En alguna imagen se veía estética _cayetana_ jeje. Preciosa calle por cierto, la he paseado unas cuantas veces.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Vale, que no había visto la noticia. Gracias por el enlace y la apreciación! Las manifestaciones en Málaga todas suelen pasar por ahí, por eso quería destacar que no es el equivalente al barrio de Salamanca. :-)

Comment: Ah vale, ese contexto me faltaba. Otro día aprendiendo cosas nuevas!

Comment: ¿Los colores en el mapa se refieren a números absolutos o relativos?

Comment: @Charo Relativos. He incluido el enlace a la página del INE, puedes "jugar" con ella poniendo otros nombres y apellidos. No la conozco en profundidad.